# How can I get angle of marker on google map

Tags: android, dictionary, bearing, azimuth

There.

I am trying to show `marker` of `current location`. I managed to get `angle(azimuth)` and `bearing`. I subtract `azimuth` from `bearing` for calculation. Then marker points in correct direction, but sometimes it points a little bit right from correct direction.

How can I get correct angle of marker?

Comment: should you just use bearing for current direction? I used just that when I was displaying similar thing

Comment: I think marker point wrong direction just with bearing.